# Link to direct another page on custom plugin in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to call insert_alert.php through this below Add New link. Please help with what code is to be added or which action or hook is required to do this.

demo1.php

```
<h3>LIST OF ALERTS
  <a href="<?php echo admin_url('admin.php?page=insert_alert_action'); ?>"
  class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" role="button">Add New</a></h3>
```

insert_alert.php *PSEUDOCODE*

```
function alert_options() {
  <div class="wrap">
  <h2>Alert</h2>
  <form method="post" action="<?php echo get_admin_url()."admin-post.php"; ?>">       
    <p><strong>Alert Title:</strong><br />
      <input type="text" name="title" size="20" required/>        
    </p>
    <p><strong>Alert Content:</strong><br />
      <textarea name="content" required></textarea>
    </p>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit-form" />        
    <p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Save Alert" /></p>
  </form>
  </div>
}
```

[image]

Comment: any problem with current code?

Comment: Hi milan, whenever i click on Addnew link it display error like you don't have access this page....

Comment: make sure that the URL you're trying to redirect is exist and you're logged in as administrator

Comment: Hi milan, i have logged as a administrator.

Comment: try that link by typing in address bar and check whether that page is exist or not?

Comment: Hi milan, already i have found my solution...